# AngularJS - mocking ngTableParams in jasmine test case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngtable

I have created an application using ng-table , the application is workign fine but when i wrote a jasmine test case i am getting.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: TableParamsProvider
```

Can anyone please tell me how to mock the `ngTableParams` and test its functionality

My code is as given below

**jasmine test case**

```
describe('Testing Controllers', function() {
    describe('Testing WorkController Controller', function() {
        var WorkController, $scope;

        beforeEach(module('wsd.workstations'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            WorkController = $controller('WorkController', {
                $rootScope: $rootScope,
                $scope: $scope
            });
        }));

        it('should searchDocuments when searchDocuments() is called', function() {
            $scope.searchDocuments();
        });
    });
});
```

**script**

```
angular.module('wsd', ['restangular', 'ngTable', 'wsd.models', 'wsd.workstations', 'wsd.workperiods', 'ngRoute'])

.config(function(RestangularProvider, $routeProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/rest/myuser');

    $routeProvider.when('/wd', {
        templateUrl: 'main/workstation/main.tpl.html',
        controller: 'WorkController',
        resolve: {
            myWorkDocuments: function(Documents) {
                return Documents.getWorkDocuments();
            }
        }
    }).when('/wp', {
        templateUrl: 'main/workperiod/main.tpl.html',
        controller: 'PeriodController',
        resolve: {
            myWorkPeriods: function(Periods) {
                return Periods.getWorkPeriods();
            }
        }
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/wd'
    });
});
```

**workstation/main.js**

```
angular.module('wsd.workstations', [])

.controller('WorkController', function($rootScope, $scope, $filter, ngTableParams)
{ 
   $scope.myValues = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}, 
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        sorting: {
            name: 'asc'     
        }
    }, {
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $scope.myValues = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myValues, params.orderBy());
            $defer.resolve($scope.myValues);
        }
    });


    $scope.searchDocuments = function() 
    {
        // some other logic
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that you app depends on ngTable. Is it inside 'main'?

Now for the test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    WorkController = $controller('WorkController', {
        $rootScope: $rootScope,
        $scope: $scope,
        $filter: $filter,
        ngTableParams: ngTableParams
    });
}));
```

Notice how you must explicitly provide every dependency as a parameter for injector.

edit: igorzg solution will work too if you don't want to test anything associated with $scope.tableParams

another edit: You need to let angular know what to inject into your controller:

```
.controller('WorkController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', function($rootScope, $scope, $filter, ngTableParams)
{ 
 // your controller code here
}]);
```

Another problem is that in your test you're loading wsd.workstations module, which **doesn't** have ngTable injected. So you need to:

```
angular.module('wsd.workstations', ['ngTable'])
```

**OR** in your test:

```
beforeEach(module('wsd'));
```

instead of:

```
beforeEach(module('wsd.workstations'));
```

Comment: No there's a minute change ....actually ng-table is defined within the main.js.............ours is the child to that, i have added the ng-route and the full script

Comment: also not only mocking i want to test the asc functionality too

Comment: I've edited the answer. What do you mean 'asc functionality'?

Comment: can we test that orderBy sorting

Comment: I already see that sorting won't work because you're trying to use $defer but you don't pass it to your controller.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't notice that $defer is injected by ngTable.

Comment: The question is about mocking ngTableParams, not writing a test for sorting.

Comment: i have wrote a seperate question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301572/testing-the-sorting-feature-in-ngtable-using-jasmine  can you please tell me some solution for that

Comment: Can you give me some solution for that sorting test cases

Answer (score 1):

Just mock it while you create instance of controller

```
    function MyNgTableParamsMock() {

    } 
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $filter) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        WorkController = $controller('WorkController', {
            $rootScope: $rootScope,
            $scope: $scope,
            $filter: $filter,
            ngTableParams: MyNgTableParamsMock  
        });
    }));
```

Comment: i am getting ReferenceError: Can&apos;t find variable: $filter

Comment: $filter should be always there because its part of angular api, to make it workable you can remove filter from inject and mock filter with some empty function but filter should be always injectable. can you paste your code ?